# how to save/load only gridvalues to/from text/xml file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

I want to save my textbox and gridvalues in text/xml file in encoded format.

but when i load my form application textbox values and gridview values should be displayed in their respective boxes.

but i want to store all the items under one file only and retrieve them as well.
But those file should be saved individually(text/xml file per user).
I should be able to save the file at once.

Please help me out it's my project module and needed badly.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you have so far? Where are you stuck? I hope you don't expect us to write the entire code from scratch for you...

Comment: Do you have a sample of the xml file you are looking to create?

Comment: actually i got one program which creates a xml tags dynamically. so right know i dont have any such type of xml sample.